# Mass-spring damper system subjected to harmonic excitation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, vibrations

[image]

The following graphs represent the steady state responses shown in red of a mass-spring-damper system subject to harmonic forcing shown in blue in the graphs below. How can you determine which of the following responses is due to a forcing frequency $ω\gg ω_n$ where $ω_n$ is the natural frequency and $ω$ is the excitation frequency of the harmonic force? I tried to solve this problem by considering the general form of the response of a mass-spring-damper system when $ω\gg ω_n$ but am not sure how to reach the conclusion that the first graph represents the response of a system due to $ω\gg ω_n$ since it is 90 degrees out of phase rather than in phase with the force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correctly looking at the general form of the response of a harmonic oscillator, where you get the $\frac{1}{\omega_n^2-\omega^2}$ proportionality term between the displacement and the force (I omit some constants here). From here, if $\omega_n\ll\omega$, you get a minus sign. So the force and displacement are just like in the 1st figure, at a 180 degrees phase shift (not 90 as you wrote though).

Answer (score -1):

The horizontal axis is scaled too narrowly to catch the resonance. Change the scaling to go from 1Hz on the left to 10,000 Hz on the right, then look for where the amplitude gets a peak in it. There's your resonance.